# Input message is not populating in the message assembly of IIB mapping node

Tags: messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/009O6.jpg)Input message is not populating in the source assembly of Mapping node in IIB.
I tried to use the MOVE but getting output as empty as shown in the picture.
If I am assigning a value I am getting the output .But Unable to move value from source to target

Comment: What's your assigning value? Can you take a screenshot of mapping design editor

Answer (score 0):

The issue fixed now, the source xsd has xs elements instead xsd. I have altered it to xsd from xs and changed the name space based on the input xml.